What is the best way of installing SDL2_gfx on Ubuntu?
Searching, I see a couple of answers, but they are about 9 years old and seem quite out of date when tried. In particular, I tried the instructions here but the attempt died with
$ ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: 3: aclocal: not found
./autogen.sh: 4: automake: not found
./autogen.sh: 5: autoconf: not found
Now you are ready to run ./configure
parallels@ubuntu-linux-22-04-02-desktop:~/SDL2_gfx-master$ ./configure
configure: error: cannot find sources (README) in . or ..

